# Create custom api to get filterable attribute for specific category in magento 2

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2, layered-navigation

I am creating api to get filterable attribute for specific category in magento 2.

We see in category page for layered navigation. I want to achieve exact same data in api.

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

    $appState = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
    $layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
    $filterList = $objectManager->create(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
        [
            'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
        ]
    );

    $category_id = 41;

    // $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $layer = $layerResolver->get();
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category_id);
    $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);

    $finalFilters = [];
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if ($filter->getItemsCount()) {
            $name = $filter->getName();
            foreach ($filter->getItems() as $item) {

                if($item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode() == 'price'){

                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['name'] = $this->Helper->removeHTML($item->getLabel()->getArguments());
                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['value'] = $item->getValue();
                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['code'] = $item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();         
                }
                else{

                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['name'] = $item->getLabel();
                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['value'] = $item->getValue();
                    $finalFilters[$name][$i]['code'] = $item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But getting following error.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The attribute model is not defined.

Comment: how did you define your api? who is throwing the error? it is not that clear what the problem is.

Comment: I am creating api in magento 2. Magento is throwing error.

Comment: I've same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is becasuse the in filter there is category also so it dont have attribute model so use below function to achieve that

```html
public function filters($categoryId)
    {
        $categoryLayer = $this->layerResolver->get()->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
        $category      = $this->getCategory();

        $filterList       = new FilterList($this->objectManager, $this->fill);
        $filterAttributes = $filterList->getFilters($categoryLayer);
        $filterArray      = [];

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($filterAttributes as $filter) {
            $attributeLabel = (string) $filter->getName();
            $attributeCode  = (string) $filter->getRequestVar();
            $items          = $filter->getItems();
            $filterValues   = [];

            $j = 0;

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($attributeCode == 'cat') {
                    $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
                    $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();
                } elseif ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
                    if ($filter->getAttributeModel()
                    && $filter->getAttributeModel()->getFrontendInput() == 'price') {
                        $filterValues[$j]['min_price'] = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
                        $filterValues[$j]['max_price'] = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
                        break;
                    }

                    $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
                    $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();

                    // Get Swatches.
                    $swatchesValues = $this->getSwatches($filter, $item, $j);
                    if (!empty($swatchesValues)) {
                        $filterValues[$j]['swatch_value'] = $swatchesValues['swatch_value'];
                        $filterValues[$j]['swatch_type']  = $swatchesValues['swatch_type'];
                    }
                }
                $j++;
            }

            if (!empty($filterValues)) {
                $filterArray['available_filter'][$attributeCode]['label']  = $attributeLabel;
                $filterArray['available_filter'][$attributeCode]['values'] = $filterValues;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return [$filterArray];
    }//end filters()
```

Comment: No, Its not return filterable attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Example\ExtendedApi\Model;

use Example\ExtendedApi\Api\FiltersInterface;

class FiltersManagement implements FiltersInterface
{

  protected $_request;
  protected $_filterableAttributeList;
  protected $_layerResolver;
  protected $_filterList;
  protected $_storeManagerInterface;
  protected $_response;
  protected $_redirFactory;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Layer\FilterableAttributesListFactory $filterableAttributeList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterListFactory $filterList,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request
  )
  {
    $this->_filterList                      = $filterList;
    $this->_filterableAttributeList         = $filterableAttributeList;
    $this->_layerResolver                   = $layerResolver;
    $this->_request                         = $request;
    $this->_storeManagerInterface           = $storeManagerInterface;
  }

  /**
    * GET  review by its ID
    *
    * @api
    * @return array
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
    *
    */
  public function getLayeredFilters()
  {
    $categoryId   = $this->_request->getParam('categoryId');
    $layer        = $this->_layerResolver->get();


    $layerType = "search";
    if ($categoryId){
      $layer->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);
      $layerType = "category";
    }

    $filterArray['store_id']  = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId();
    $filterableAttributesList = $this->_filterableAttributeList->create($layerType);

    $filterList = $this->_filterList->create(['filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributesList]);
    $filters    = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($filters as $filter)
    {
        // Don't show options with no items
      if (! $filter->getItemsCount()) {continue;}

      $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName();
      $items           = $filter->getItems();
      $filterValues    = array();

      $j = 0;
      foreach($items as $item)
      {
        $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
        $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();
        $filterValues[$j]['count']   = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
        $filterValues[$j]['url']     = $item->getUrl();   //Gives filter url.
        $j++;
      }

      if(!empty($filterValues) && count($filterValues)>1)
      {
        $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] =  $filterValues;
      }
      $i++;

    }

    if (!isset($filterArray["availablefilter"])) {
      $filterArray['availablefilter'] = "No filters to show.";
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $this->response = json_encode($filterArray);
    print_r($this->response,false);
    die();
  }

}
```